# Excel VBA Used Columns

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel file is huge and I found out that the reason is in the unused columns. If I delete them the file has a normal size.
The unused columns are just blanks or at least appear to be blanks. However, something must be contained in them.
How can I find out what and how can I reset the UsedRange to the actual number of columns with content?

I tried the following:

```
 myLastCol = _
   .Cells.Find("*", after:=.Cells(1), _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious, _
    searchorder:=xlByColumns).Column
```

And also

```
myLastCol=ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

Both would return the value `16383`. Any suggestions? How can this happen (I am sure it has something to do with the Macro I wrote)?

Comment: Do you have a row that is **always** filled with a number to the extent of your data? Do you have one with text that is always filled to the extent of your data?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to repair the mistake that your sub procedure makes every time you run it or do you want to fix the sub procedure so it doesn't make the  mistake? I would recommend the latter.

Comment: This often happens when erroneous formats or such are applied to entire columns or rows and while the extraneous rows *seem* blank, they actually have some style or format applied to them which considers them to be in the `UsedRange`. If your problem occurs because the code executes over and over again and when you hit this it calculates, review and refactor your code based on what I wrote above. Otherwise, simply delete the extra rows | columns and move on with life :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just delete the unused columns? If so what about this solution?

```
Sub DeleteUnusedColumns()

        Dim colRange As Range
        Dim c As Long

    'Define the target range
        Set colRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    'Iterate through the columns
        For c = colRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

    'If the column is empty then you can delete it
           If Application.CountA(Columns(c).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
           Columns(c).Delete
           End If

    'Increment the counter down
        Next c
    End Sub

End Sub
```